# where does leaflet store the tiles for a tilelayer

Tags: leaflet, tile, imagedata

I have an elevation tilelayer in Leaflet and would like to access the individual tile images in order to access their elevation data via the imageData object

Where are the tile images stored within Leaflets tileLayer object?

Answer (score 0):

There is no public function for this but you can access it via `tile._tiles`

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/rHpmBfqRkPRCypBs